# How to get a notification if Google Script's "My Executions" shows that a script hasn't run in specified time

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, notifications, crash

I have a Google Script running every 5 minutes. It works except randomly there are sudden crashes and the script/trigger won't survive that. So, for many different reasons, the script stops running after some weeks of continuing runtime. At this point, I would need a notification.

How can I get a notification if a function (script) hasn't run in say 2 hours? Doesn't matter what the technique/notification is, but probably email would be great for the notification. I don't think the solution can be in the script code itself, because the script randomly (every few weeks) crashes at Google's side and there's nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script installable triggers automatically set an email notification. You could edit when it should be sent (i.e. send immediately) and you could add more notifications. NOTE: This can only be done manually.

The above will work for "normal" failures but it there is a service outage or other platforms failures the notification might not be sent.

One option is to log the executions somewhere then set a second trigger to check that the first trigger ran every time that it should do it as expected. NOTE: The failure that prevented that the first trigger run might also prevent that his second trigger run i.e. a service outage so you might want to set other monitoring measures accordingly the the severity/priority of this failure and your project budget.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I believe the crashes I've encountered are platform failures. However, as these happen only e.g. once in two months, it's really difficult to debug what's happening. About the Trigger Failure notification settings at https://script.google.com/home/triggers – I don't know why I haven't received any of these Failure emails anymore (last one is from February). Possibly the trigger was automatically deleted (platform failure?) and therefore the Failure notification process didn't exist anymore. I'll continue searching for some simple but effective solution.